# Find an upper bound for $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}} e^{-t} \sin (\frac{\pi t} {2})$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

How can I determine an upper bound on $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}} e^{-t} \sin (\frac{\pi t} {2})$, i.e. an upper bound on $f^{(n+1)} (t)$? We are given that $t \in [0, 3]$ as well as the following hint: How many terms are in $f^{(n+1)}$ and what is an upper bound for each of them?

So far I have arrived at, that for the derivative $f^{(n+1)}$ we have n+2 terms and I understand that if we can then find an upper bound on these terms, we can then arrive at an upper bound for the derivative, namely (n+2) times this upper bound. However, I cannot seem to derive an upper bound on the terms of the derivatives.

The derivatives will contain terms multiplied by either $\cos(\frac{\pi t} {2})$ or $\sin(\frac{\pi t} {2})$ which are both upper bounded by 1, and we also have that $e^{-t} \leq 1$ for $t \in [0, 3]$.

Comment: Key observation : compute the $n+1$st derivative of $e^{(−1+i\pi/2)t}$ then take its imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

$$g(x) :=e^{ax } \sin(bx+c)$$
$$g'(x)=ae^{ax } \sin(bx+c) +be^{ax } \cos(bx+c)$$
let $r^2 =a^2+b^2$ and let $\theta =\arcsin(\frac{b}{r^2})$
$$g'(x)=r^2 e^{ax}\sin(bx+c +\theta) $$
With that we can prove by induction that $g^{(n)}(x)=r^{2n} e^{ax}\sin(bx+c +n \theta) $.

For your function $f(t)=e^{-t} \sin(\frac{\pi t}{2})$ and $r^2=1+\frac{{\pi}^2}{4}$ and $\theta= \arcsin(\frac{{\pi }}{2r^2})$
note that $e^{-t}$ for all $t \in [0,3] \le 1$ and $\sin(y) \le 1 \forall x\in [0,3]$ so we have that:

$$f^{(n)}(t)=(1+\frac{{\pi}^2}{4})^n e^{-t} \sin(\frac{\pi t}{2}+n\theta)\le (1+\frac{{\pi}^2}{4})^n $$